# Why Netty use boss and work eventloop rather than one eventloop

Tags: netty

I've a question about Netty.
Seems it use a boss eventLoop to keep accepting connection, and another worker eventLoop to keep doing data I/O.

The source code showed that one eventLoop will repeat calling select/poll/epoll. So there will be more than one eventLoop burning the CPU. Why can't netty just use one eventloop to handle both server listen socket and accepted socket?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331809/netty-bootstrap-with-boss-group-or-with-just-with-workers-eventloopgroup?rq=1 may also help understand the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an architecture called SEDA. The benefit of Boss eventloop is : The thread you used to accept connection will not be blocked by IO threads which used to read the data from socket and then do the work in handler. You could also Use ExecutionHandler to help eventloop. Netty is changing and improving the thread modeling. And changed a lot in Netty 4.

Comment: If I put all the logic execution in ExecutionHandler, so the I/O thread will return immediately, can I say use one EventLoopGroup as Boss and Worker is better than use tow?

Comment: yes, you can. And i think you could do some performance testing. My guess is : If you application /server need to handle a lot of concurrent connection and on each connection the traffic is not so much. Then two would be better. Or i think one would be good enough.